# How to show property like username in all pages (all Components) ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I get the `UserName` and other information about the user from the server by Axios after a successful login and I want to pass this information to my `Header` component to show it on all pages.

I can send properties by `<Header userName={this.state.UserName}` to the  `Header` component and it is okay, but when I go to another component from header I lose it and must set state for save username.

Is there any solution to have some property in all Components like Session in Java?

Comment: You could just hold that value in state somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are solutions to use some property in all components in React. You will need a state management tool for this. The 2 most commonly used ones are Redux and React's Context API.